# powershell find ms word files through keywords

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I have made a script that should return a specific word document.

It searches for a keyword in the document to find the right file. It finds the file, but also a lot of other files that **does not** contain the keyword, but it says it **does** contain the keyword

What am I doing wrong please.

Regards

```bsh
#Client modules laden (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"


#Folder om mee verbinding te maken
$SourceFolder = "c:\test"
cd $SourceFolder

#Keywords waarop gezocht moet worden
$keyword1 = "25189"
$Forward = $true
$MatchWholeWord = $true


$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse| Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*.doc*'} 

foreach ($doc in $docs)
{
    $condition1 = $word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName).Content.Find.Execute($keyword1,$Forward,$MatchWholeWord)

    if ($condition1 -match $true)
    {
        #$word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
        Write-Host -f Cyan "$doc contains $keyword1"
        #Move-Item -Path $doc.FullName -Destination $destination
        $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
    }
    else
    {
        $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
        Write-Host -f Red "$doc does not contain $keyword1"
    }
#Write-host -f Green $doc.Name 

}
$document.close()
Write-Host $doc.FullName
Stop-Process -Name "WINWORD"
```

Answer (score 0):

When i run your script it works perfectly. I can't find the problem. Could you try my script. There are no major changes but maybe this will work for you:

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"

#Folder om mee verbinding te maken
$SourceFolder = "c:\temp"
cd $SourceFolder

#Keywords waarop gezocht moet worden
$keyword1 = "25189"
$Forward = $true
$MatchWholeWord = $true

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$docs = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Include @("*.doc", "*.docx") -Recurse

foreach ($doc in $docs)
{
    $condition1 = $Word.Documents.Open($doc.FullName).Content.Find.Execute($keyword1,$Forward,$MatchWholeWord)

    switch($condition1)
    {
        $true
        {
            #$word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
            Write-Host -f Cyan "$doc contains the Keyword: '$keyword1'"
            #Move-Item -Path $doc.FullName -Destination $destination
            $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
        }

        $false
        {
            $word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()
            Write-Host -f Red "$doc does not contains the Keyword: $keyword1"
        }
    }

    Write-Host "Filename '$($doc.Fullname)"
    Write-Host "`r"
}

Stop-Process -Name "WINWORD"
```

Comment: Could it be that the keyword is seen as a numeric value? If so. How do you solve it?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can test that by removing the " " ... $keyword1 = 25189 ... This way Powershell will handle this as an integer [INT]

Comment: I tested it and the problem was not the script but the Word documents!

Comment: Great to hear tou figured it out! Don't forget to mark the answer for other people ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@Mike
Thank you for helping me.

Your script works better than mine, but it also finds files that does not contain the keyword and says it contains the keyword in this line Write-Host -f Cyan "$doc contains the Keyword: '$keyword1'".

It even finds files where it says of the same file "$doc contains the Keyword: '$keyword1'" and "$doc does not contain the Keyword: '$keyword1'".

Comment: Geen dank ;)

What if you create two Test-files, one with a value 25189 and one with a value 25181. Maybe it's something in the files you query.

I tested it like this way and get the following output:
**C:\temp\test1.docx contains the Keyword: '25189'
Filename 'C:\temp\test1.docx.FullName'**

**C:\temp\test2.docx does not contains the Keyword: 25189
Filename 'C:\temp\test2.docx.FullName'**